# Splitting integer array into multiple chunks in different length in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<int> mainList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

List<int> chukLengths= [2,4,4,4,2]
```

Expected Result:

```
[[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14],[15,16]]
```

I wanna split ***mainList*** to 5 chunks with mentioned ***chunkLength***.
How to resolve it in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the array of your chunks and slice off necessary chunks off the main array. Each iteration your get the chunk itself by using `sublist()` and then you delete the chunk from the initial array using `removeRange()`

Here is the code:

```dart
List<int> mainList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
List<int> chukLengths= [2,4,4,4,2];

List<List<int>> splitIntoChunks(List<int> list, List<int> chunks) {
  List<List<int>> result = [];
  

  for (int chunk in chunks) {
    result.add(list.sublist(0, chunk));
    list.removeRange(0, chunk);
  }
  
  return result;
}

void main() {
  print(splitIntoChunks(mainList, chukLengths)); // [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16]]
}
```

Comment: Shorter: `List<List<T>> splitIntoChunks<T>(List<T> list, List<int> chunkLengths) => [for (var i = 0, s = 0; i < chunkLengths.length; i++) list.sublist(s, s += chunkLengths[i])];`